# Settings in php.ini partially ignored?

Tags: php, apache, configuration, ini, error-reporting

Somehow my php.ini is partially ignored. For instance, I can change the setting for displaying errors, but not for error reporting.

The setup is the following:

```
$ php -i | grep "Configuration file"
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/php5/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
```

Let’s check the the values of error_reporting and display_errors:

```
grep "error_reporting\|display_errors"
error_reporting => 32767 => 32767
display_errors => Off => Off
```

Let’s change the values (error_reporting = E_ERROR, display_errors = on), restart Apache and check again:

```
$ sudo nano /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
$ sudo apachectl restart
$ php -i | grep "error_reporting\|display_errors"
error_reporting => 32767 => 32767
display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT
```

It doesn’t matter where I check these settings. They’re the same on both Browser and Terminal. error_reporting is ALWAYS 32767 (=E_ALL).

Even the setting disable_functions did not help at all.

```
disable_functions = error_reporting
```

Same goes for timezone, the setting is simply ignored. But post_max_size and upload_max_filesize are alterable.

What’s wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By installing PHP 5.5 via

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.5
```

a file named 99-liip-developer.ini will be installed in /usr/local/php5/php.d. This overwrites some settings (see http://php-osx.liip.ch/#faq).

After renaming or deleting the file, PHP works as expected.

I found this out by

```
$ php -i | grep "Scan this dir for additional"
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/php5/php.d
grep -R "error_reporting" /usr/local/php5/php.d/
```

Credits to suchit!

Answer (score 0):

Hi do you have set_error_handler in your code?

```
set_error_handler("my_error_handler"); // override error_reporting()
```